# javascript window.onload scope

Tags: javascript, scope

Can someone explain why the alert returns "undefined" instead of "hello"?

```
window.onload = function() {  
    var a = 'hello';  
    alert(window.a);  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Named variables are defined with the var statement. When used inside of a function, var defines variables with function-scope." - ([source](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html))

To be accessible globally, and particularly to make `a` a member of the `window` object, alter your code in this way:

```
var a; // defined in the global scope
window.onload = function() {  
    a = 'hello'; // initialized
    alert(window.a);  
}
```

Or in this way:

```
var b = 'world'; //defined and initialized in the global scope
window.onload = function() {  
    alert(window.b);  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

variable 'a' is not part of window in your context.

a is scoped to the anonymous function you've assigned to onload.

you COULD add a as a member of window if you wanted:

```
window.onload = function() {  
    window.a = 'hello';  
    alert(window.a);  
}
```

but i'd suggest against doing so.